# KNN providing the same result regardless of K value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

I have a KNearestNeighbor classifier, that I have tried to fit with my data.

I tried, with 100, 1000 and 10000 data entries, and got some different results.

With 1000 entries I got the following graph for my code

```
error_rate = []

for i in range(1,40):
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
...


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(error_rate, color='blue', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
     markerfacecolor='red', markersize=10)
plt.title('Error Rate vs. K Value')
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Error Rate')
```

[image: Graph]

unlike some of my other data entries, this one had a fairly large `error_rate`

when I printed the results

```
print(classification_report(y_test, pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred))
```

the results went fairly well

[image]

I almost the same result regardless, of the K-value in the classification report and confusion matrix

Comment: what does your last line mean? "I almost the same result regardless, of the K-value in the classification re"

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it means, that almost whatever the K-value i specify, the confusion matrix and calissification report, has almost identical results